# Table (page width) in multicol?

Tags: floats, multicol

I'm writing a scientific article (two-column style), and I need to show some results in a table with lots of columns, so I have to put a page-width table in the bottom of the page. How can I do?

Comment: may be use the multicols package, and do \begin{multicols}{2} ...and then end it when you want to insert the table using \end{multicols}. After the table is there,  you can restart the multicols after that again if needed.

Comment: it was that easy? awesome! if you put that as an answer, I'll check it. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you're using a document class provided by the journal or sponsoring organization, and assuming that this document class uses the `twocolumn` option, the only place on a page where LaTeX will place a full-width float (with a `table*` or `figure*` environment) is at the *top*. Would it be acceptable for your purposes to have the floats at the top of a page?

Comment: Indeed, it can be acceptable. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}`, you can control when to start and end the 2 columns using `multicol` package as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}  %adjust as needed
\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.01pt} %adjust as needed
\renewcommand{\columnseprulecolor}{\color[rgb]{0.6,0.6,0.6}} %adjust as needed

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
text
\end{multicols}

\begin{tabular}{....} %this will now use the full page
..........
\end{tabular}

\begin{multicols}{2}
text
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This way the table doesn't float to the bottom unless you write your text to the exact right length, so despite the checkmark I don't think this really answer the initial question.